# Outlook calendar conditional formatting, for the mettings where the attendees (other than me) didn't confirm their presence?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, conditional-formatting, calendar

How can I highlight the meetings where my guests didn't confirm their presence? I would like to know when I need to sned a reminder to my clients before a meeting is up...

Comment: Not within the easy conditional-formatting interface, though maybe it can be done through an SQL calendar filter? If you're open to using a Macro to do this, then maybe someone can adapt this VBA code to check each meeting: https://www.slipstick.com/developer/send-an-email-to-attendees-who-have-not-responded/

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that you need to reminder non-responders manully, as mentioned in this article: [Sending meeting reminders to non-responders](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/390).

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.